# IP address for API whitelisting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, web-deployment

I am currently developing a Web app (React + Nodejs) for which I would like to use a third-party API. After a few email exchanges with the third-party, they agreed to give me access to their API and are now asking me what is my 'global IP address'. I suppose this is for whitelisting purpose. Having not deployed the app anywhere yet, I do not have an IP address to provide. A few questions:

1. Does that mean that I need to already buy a domain now and deploy a server on it?
2. Let's say I have a domain and got access to the API; would that still be possible to use Postman (through a proxy?)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If they're restricting by IP they need to know any and all addresses you're using to access it, and this includes your dev machine if that's the case. Once you deploy you'll be able to figure out what your IP(s) are.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I thought about giving at least my IP for testing purpose through Postman, but the address could be a dynamic one and could change at some point. So just wondering if there is a more « robust » way of doing things.

Comment: If you're getting listed like this, you really need some kind of static IP you can depend on. This comes in many forms, from a VPS to a VPN with such an option. If you're deploying on a cloud service, your IP might flap around a lot as your app gets migrated unless you have control over that.

Comment: I’ve indeed looked a bit at some solutions like Heroku but there is no way to get a static address from my understanding. I see that Google Cloud/AWS allows to reserve a static IP address, not sure that’s the easiest way though...

Comment: You can get a VPS (EC2, Linode, Digital Ocean, OVH, etc.) for as little as $5/mo. If you're familiar with the basics of system setup, that's the best way to go. Otherwise you're floating in the clouds, as it were.

Comment: Will take a look at that and how the deployment works. Thank you so much, I am not used to handle infrastructure and such. :D

Comment: This is sort of a demonstration of why locking to specific IPs is a futile and annoying exercise, but some IT admins insist on it because they don't know of better methods. When all you have is a firewall, all your security policies are firewall rules.

Comment: Indeed. At least it is pushing me to dive into something I usually avoid. :’)

Comment: @MrBushido did you figure this out?

Comment: From what I remember, no I didn’t. I got in the end the access to the API by explaining the situation. 